# C++11 "enumerated types" (17.5.2.1.2)

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

A quote from C++11 standard (17.5.2.1.2 Enumerated types):

> 1 Several types defined in Clause 27 are *enumerated types*. Each enumerated type may be implemented as an enumeration or as a synonym for an enumeration (Such as an integer type, with constant integer values (3.9.1)).
>
> 2 The enumerated type *enumerated* can be written:

```
enum enumerated { V0 , V1 , V2 , V3 , ..... };
static const enumerated C0 (V0 );
static const enumerated C1 (V1 );
static const enumerated C2 (V2 );
static const enumerated C3 (V3 );
.....
```

> 3 Here, the names C0, C1, etc. represent *enumerated elements* for this particular enumerated type. All such elements have distinct values.

One of such "enumerated types" is "seekdir" from class ios_base (27.5.3 Class ios_base):

```
// 27.5.3.1.5 seekdir
typedef T4 seekdir;
static constexpr fmtflags beg = unspecified ;
static constexpr fmtflags cur = unspecified ;
static constexpr fmtflags end = unspecified ;
```

and

> 27.5.3.1.5 Type ios_base::seekdir [ios::seekdir]

```
typedef T4 seekdir;
```

> 1 The type seekdir is an enumerated type (17.5.2.1.2) that contains the elements indicated in Table 126.

So, the ONLY reason those static const and constexpr members are required is because "enumerated types" are allowed to be implemented as integer type (i.e. when *enumerated* is int we need to define constants in place of enumerators), right?

**Question 1**. If library vendor decides to implement seekdir as enum does he still have to define static constants for enumeration values?

**Question 2**. WHY "enumerated types" are allowed to be implemented as integer types in the first place? I.e. when enum implementation (and in C++11 enums can have any underlying integer type) without those static constant members can be worse than integer type implementation?

Comment: Bonus question: Why does is say `static constexpr fmtflags beg = unspecified ;` in the synopsis of `ios_base` instead of `static constexpr seekdir beg = unspecified ;`? - I just reported that to the Standard guys, seems to be a typo.

Comment: @Daniel "reported that to the Standard guys" - cool, how do you do that? :) Also, TBH, even after copy-pasting that quote I havn't noticed that typo myself.

Comment: I wrote an email to the address given on the cover page of the Standard. Should be good enough for such an obvious typo I guess. Generally, you should follow [these guidelines](http://isocpp.org/std/submit-a-library-issue).

Comment: @DanielFrey - there is no e-mail address on the cover page of the standard. I assume you mean the draft that you're using as a stand-in for the actual standard.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Oops, correct :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original reason for requiring objects for the values of enumerated types was so that you could take their address. That always struck me as silly, but there was quite a bit of overdesign in the early stages of standardization.

Comment: Funny, I even had that as part of my answer and edited it away because I couldn't for the live of it think of an example where it might be useful :)

Comment: @Pete So allowing integer type for "enumerated types" and requiring static const class members in C++11 is just another case of backwards compatibility? And even if a vendor decides to use for ex. "enum seekdir: int" he would still need to define those static constexpr members?

Comment: @PowerGamer, yes, the standard requires an implementation to define named objects that have addresses, it can't just define enumerators.

Answer (score 6):

When the standard was written, strongly-typed enums weren't available and the problem with plain `enum` is, that their internal type is unspecified and may *change* depending on compiler switches.

For `seekdir`, it could be `int` or `byte` (as an example), both would be valid representations. GCC has an command line option for that (`--short-enums` or `-fshort-enums`), by default it would use `int` for all `enum`s as the smallest type, but with the option it would use the smallest type that could contain all values.

That means that if a real `enum` is used in a function signature, the symbol may change and you'd need to recompile everything. This is why the Standard allows other options, why it's important for the Standard Library implementation to have control over the type and this is why it is allowed to resort to specific integer types.

Comment: @Daniel Are you implying that back in the day (before C++11) Standard library implementations in GCC used integer type instead of enum for seekdir because of the problem you describe?

Comment: @PowerGamer, in the specific case of GCC, no, `seekdir` has been a typedef for `enum _Ios_Seekdir` as long as I can remember

Comment: @PowerGamer: I'm not implying anything specific, as each compiler and Standard library can find other ways to deal with it. In case of libstdc++, I think this is the reason for `_S_ios_seekdir_end = 1L << 16` in `ios_base.h`, so it never gets reduced to anything smaller than `int`, even with `-fshort-enums`.

Comment: @DanielFrey Since a little trick like `_S_ios_seekdir_end = 1L << 16` solves the need to "recompile everything", what you described in your answer cannot be counted as advantage of integer types over enums (even for pre-C++11 enums). I'll accept Pete's answer then (but anyway thanks for your contribution).

Comment: @PowerGamer: OK, I understand that my wording was a bit too strong and I fixed it. Note that I tried to answer the question why the standard allows it, not if it is really needed.